# Поиск значения выборка в Excel

Tags: excel

Добрый день. Есть таблица такого вида (ниже). Это только начало таблицы, строк около 500. Некоторые предметы, например "Русский язык" и др. повторяются. Нужно посчитать сумму по всем повторяющимся предметам, по неповторяющимся просто значение. Писал формулу так:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕНД(ВПР(B5;B3:C15;2));ВПР(B5;B3:C15;2); 0)
```

не работает. Если писать просто

```
=ВПР(B5;B3:C15;2)
```

получается что если значение не найдено, общее значение - "#Н/Д". Огромная просьба помочь. Заранее спасибо.

```
1   Русский язык            0
2   Литература              0
3   Иностранный язык        78
4   История                 0
5   Обществознание          0
6   География               8
7   Естествознание          32
8   Физическая культура     114
9   ОБЖ                     4
10  Математика              0
11  Информатика и ИКТ       60
12  Экономика               8
13  Право                   0
14  ****                 .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужно посчитать сумму по всем
> повторяющимся предметам

Суммировать с помощью *ВПР()* не получится.
Функция ищет первое вхождение значения в диапазон и по нему определяет значение другого столбца. Если поиск по неточному соответствию, то найдется ближайшее меньшее значение. Естественно, если значения в первом столбце диапазона нет (при поиске точного сообветствия) или нет меньшего (при неточном поиске), то формула с данной функцией покажет ошибку - нет данных.

Можно понять, что нужна сумма по всем предметам, которые повторяются, т.е.: если 2 математики и 3 русских, то суммировать 5 значений.

Но все же предположу, что нужна сумма значений, относящихся к одному предмету. Для примера выше: сумма 2-х значений по математике, сумма 3-х значений по русскому. В таком случае применима функция, суммирующая по условию:
*СУММЕСЛИ(диапазон(предметов);предмет;диапазон(чисел))*

=СУММЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$500;D2;$C$2:$C$500)

В *D2* - название предмета